# Disable emails for new user registration

Tags: users, user-registration, authentication

I want to disable the default email that is send when user is registered.
I am using this plugin for email verification `User Verification
By PickPlugins`, which sends an email with confirmation link, but the problem is that by default and WordPress send an email via `pluggable.php`:

```
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ){...}
```

I am using a theme (which I am extending with a child theme), which calls `wp_create_user`. I have replaced that parent theme function and in my `functions.php` I have added:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    remove_action( 'register_new_user',   'wp_send_new_user_notifications'         
);

add_action(    'register_new_user',   'wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications' );
});

function wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications(  $user_id, $notify = 'user' ){
    wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify  );
}
```

The problem is, it still send both emails, from the plugin and default WordPress email for new user registration. I don't know how to disable this email.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code to be working, simply put it in a plugin.
It should then work!

Comment: Why doesn't work in `functions.php` for the active theme, but will work in a plugin ?

Comment: Long story short, it's related to the order of which plugins and theme load. Some hooks needs to fire before others.

Comment: I have created a plugin and it is same. It seems that it doesn't hook the function.

Comment: Even if I comment `//add_action(register...`, it still sends the default email.

Answer (score 0):

Move the parameter default into the function.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_action( 'register_new_user',   'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );        
 });

add_action(    'register_new_user',   'wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications' );

function wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications(  $user_id ){
    wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'user' );
}
```

Changed the wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications function to use the wp_new_user_notification as opposed to the action directly. Even though it works, it is more likely to break in a WordPress update.

I would also mention maybe instead of removing the action on init, use the register_new_user action and set at a lower priority. WordPress core uses 10 by default, so putting yours at 9 or below will work.

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', function(){
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
}, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried several suggestions but they didn't work for me.
Found a piece of code at [SmartWP.com](https://smartwp.com/disable-wordpress-new-user-notification-email/) for disabling the admin notification and changed the code slightly and this one finally worked great

```
function smartwp_disable_new_user_notifications() {
//Remove original use created emails
remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'register_new_user', 'smartwp_send_new_user_notifications' );
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'smartwp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );} 

function smartwp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify = 'admin' ) {
if ( empty($notify) || $notify == 'user' ) {
  return;
}elseif( $notify == 'both' ){
    //Only send the admin their email, not the user
    $notify = 'admin';
}
wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify );}

add_action( 'init', 'smartwp_disable_new_user_notifications' );
```